# confide laravel Declaration of Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser::save() should be compatible with Arde

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, hybridauth

I've modified upon the excellent Laravel 4 bootstrap and suddenly I am getting the error when I go to the route user/login:

```
Declaration of Zizaco\Confide\ConfideUser::save() should be compatible with
LaravelBook\Ardent\Ardent::save(array $rules = Array, array $customMessages = Array, 
array $options = Array, Closure $beforeSave = NULL, Closure 
$afterSave = NULL, $force = false)
```

I had added HybridAuth to composer and updated so I wonder if that had caused incompatibility issues with Confide or Ardent but when I remove it and update (as well as reverting to previous commits) I still get the error.

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Jon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ardent has added an additional `$force` parameter to their `save()` method.

The solution, for now, is to require a specific commit in your composer file:

```
    "laravelbook/ardent": "dev-master#2d1d70ea835b8c53cfe4fc60315a8ee5c672ba19"
```

You can follow the discussion in [issue #113](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/issues/113) on GitHub.

Comment: Ahh thanks very much. I'm new to the composer (and Laravel) world and is there any workflow recommended in development to prevent such a scenario in future where a composer update would break the whole app as a developer's latest master commit will break other packages?

Is the solution to only perform an update in dev and run tests to check everything's still working and then if it is, do it on production?

thx again.